# Adapter for 1/4" electric screwdriver to hold 3/8" bit

Tags: screwdriver, bits

I have a [screw driver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LYJHVXV) that supports 1/4" bits. I also got a [hole saw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004YK8DMY) , but it's apparently 3/8" hex. Is there anything that can adapt one to another? I need to cut a few holes in very soft material so I think the power of this screwdriver will be enough, but I can't find the right adapter.

Comment: Might be a bit clunky, but you might already have a 1/4" to 3/8" square socket driver and a 3/8" deep socket.

Comment: I don't have these. Both the saw and my screwdriver are hex. I just started learning this crazy world of adapters and metric vs imperial and all that.

Comment: Try if this works for you. Scrolling down to a little past the midpoint of the article to see size details. https://www.ebay.com/itm/4-pc-1-4-to-3-8-1-2-inch-Drive-Socket-Adapter-Reducer-Air-Impact-Set-NEW-/231476450676

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of ways you can adapt a 3/8" bit onto a 1/4" drive. That's actually not your *real* problem.

The real problem is that there is no way a basic *screwdriver* is going to be able to make effective use of a hole saw! Maybe through a thin layer of cardboard, but that's about it.

This is a classic example of "looks like it should work, but really the wrong tool for the job".  Like trying to use an E Z Bake oven to cook your Thanksgiving turkey. A typical battery powered "drill/driver" can be used perfectly well as a power screwdriver. But that typically has a **much** larger and faster motor, a bigger battery (this screwdriver is 4V - most drill/drivers are now 18V or more, though a 12V drill/driver is often good enough) and can be adjusted to hold different size bits (though again, that's not the main problem here).

I wouldn't expect to get anything for $19 that would do the job well. *Actually*, I just searched and found a [Harbor Freight drill/driver](https://www.harborfreight.com/power-tools/drills-drivers/cordless-drills-drivers/12v-cordless-38-in-drilldriver-kit-57366.html) - 3/8" (solves the original problem), 12V (good enough for basic drilling). Though if I were shopping for more than a "throwaway" I'd look to 18V or 20V, depending on the brand.

One more factor to consider: RPM. A quick search found that hole saw drilling in metal is generally in the "few hundred" RPM. Hole sawing drilling in wood is in more of the "one thousand to two thousand" RPM range. The sample Harbor Freight 12V drill/driver is rated at 550 RPM. A similar 18V model is rated at 900 RPM, and one of their 20V models (Harbor Freight but different brand) is rated at 2,000 RPM. Your current screwdriver: 180 RPM.

(I have no connection with Harbor Freight, they're just the one source I thought of that might have a real drill/driver at a "little screwdriver" price, and they do.)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the time and all the details.

I need to cut holes in IKEA cabinet backings, which are really like cardboard, I could cut it with a knife but I want a "clean" circular cut.

So, how can I adapt this saw to my screwdriver? I don't want to buy a "proper drill" since I will not have any use for it but it will take up space in my tiny apartment.

Comment: After many hours of searching I got these couple of things, I hope one of them works:

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00004RH2R
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073PRY9W6

Comment: In theory that should work. Assumption is that hex base is 1/4", but it doesn't actually say that anywhere that I could see. I'm skeptical though about speed & power to actually get any holes drilled. I've done my share of hole sawing - it is not always as easy as you expect it to be, and more speed & power can make a **big** difference.

Comment: Yeah there are many of these "universal adapters" and some are 3/8" some are 1/4". One of the reviewers said it's "1/4 in drive".

I'll report back if it works.

Ideally I'd find a normal adapter, but I can't find anything that does this. I found the ones that do it the other way around, but not exactly what I need.

Comment: manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact: "There are plenty of ways you can adapt a 3/8" bit onto a 1/4" drive"

Could you please give a couple examples?

Comment: The two gadgets you linked from Amazon (a magnetic bit holder and a "universal" bit) are two ways; another is a simple "3/8" hex bit" that has a 1/4" drive shaft (i.e., one of a set of hex bits). But the bottom line is I don't think *anything* will work *effectively* with a hole saw on a 4V screwdriver. [Need more power!](https://memegenerator.net/instance/62648994/captain-kirk-concentrating-mr-scott-i-must-have-more-power)